# get ALL id's of children elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ecmascript-6

How do I get an array or something similar with **ALL** the id's of elements to a certain div?

#### Let's say I have someting like this:

```
<div id="parent-div">
    <div id="div-no-1"></div>
    <div id="div-no-2"></div>
    <div id="div-no-3"></div>
    <div id="div-no-4"></div>
</div>
```

#### I would then like an array that look's something like this

```
parent-div [
    0: "div-no-1",
    1: "div-no-2",
    2: "div-no-3",
    3: "div-no-3"
];
```

#### I've tried this...

```
$("#parent-div > div").attr("id");
```

...but it only gives me the first childs id, e.g. `div-no-1`. I want ALL of them

Comment: Are you trying to output an array of strings or an array of JavaScript plain objects?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use jQuery's [`each`](https://api.jquery.com/each) and `push` the `id` to the array:

```js
var parentDiv = [];
$("#parent-div > div").each((index, elem) => {
  parentDiv.push(elem.id);
});

console.log(parentDiv);
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
<div id="parent-div">
    <div id="div-no-1"></div>
    <div id="div-no-2"></div>
    <div id="div-no-3"></div>
    <div id="div-no-4"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 13):

An alternative to Jack Bashford's solution using [`$.map`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.map/):

```js
const divIds = $.map($('#parent-div > div'), div => div.id);

console.log(divIds);
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
<div id="parent-div">
  <div id="div-no-1"></div>
  <div id="div-no-2"></div>
  <div id="div-no-3"></div>
  <div id="div-no-4"></div>
</div>
```

Or, using [`.map`](http://api.jquery.com/map/) and [`.get`](http://api.jquery.com/get/#get2):

```js
const divIds = $('#parent-div > div').map((i, div) => div.id).get();

console.log(divIds);
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
<div id="parent-div">
  <div id="div-no-1"></div>
  <div id="div-no-2"></div>
  <div id="div-no-3"></div>
  <div id="div-no-4"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 9):

This can be done in plain JavaScript using `document.querySelectorAll('#paren-div > div')` followed by a `map()` and some destructuring to get the id.

```js
const ids = [...document.querySelectorAll('#parent-div > div')].map(({ id }) => id);

console.log(ids);
```

```html
<div id="parent-div">
    <div id="div-no-1"></div>
    <div id="div-no-2"></div>
    <div id="div-no-3"></div>
    <div id="div-no-4"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 8):

If you want to do it in pure JavaScript, you can just get the children of the parent element and then loop over the result and push the ids into an array.

```js
var children = document.getElementById("parent-div").children;

var idArr = [];

for (var i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
  idArr.push(children[i].id);
}

console.log(idArr);
```

```html
<div id="parent-div">
    <div id="div-no-1"></div>
    <div id="div-no-2"></div>
    <div id="div-no-3"></div>
    <div id="div-no-4"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

The without jquery solution :

```js
const elements = [...document.querySelectorAll('#parent-div *[id]')];

console.log(elements.map(({ id }) => id));
```

```html
<div id="parent-div">
    <div id="div-no-1"></div>
    <div id="div-no-2"></div>
    <div id="div-no-3"></div>
    <div id="div-no-4"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

Give [map](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.map/) a try

```js
var arr = jQuery.map($("#parent-div").children(), function (d) {
  return $(d).attr("id");
});
console.log(arr);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="parent-div">
    <div id="div-no-1"></div>
    <div id="div-no-2"></div>
    <div id="div-no-3"></div>
    <div id="div-no-4"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

You can try this:

```js
// Make an empty arary to push ids into
var arrayOfIds = [];

// Select parent element
var parentElement = document.querySelector('#parent-div');

// Select child elements
var childElements = parentElement.querySelectorAll("div");

// Push the id attribute of every child element
// Into he previousely created array
for (var i = 0; i < childElements.length; i++) {
  arrayOfIds.push(childElements[i].getAttribute("id"));
}

console.log(arrayOfIds);
```

```html
<div id="parent-div">
    <div id="div-no-1"></div>
    <div id="div-no-2"></div>
    <div id="div-no-3"></div>
    <div id="div-no-4"></div>
</div>
```

You can use `.getAttribute("class")` to get the CSS classes of all the elements, or any other attribute, by the same logic.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `.querySelectorAll()` with [Descendant combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Descendant_combinator)

> Descendant  combinator The   (space) combinator selects nodes that are
>   descendants of the first element. Syntax: `A B`

`"#parent-id [id]"` to match all child nodes having an `id` attribute, spread syntax to convert `NodeList` to `Array` and `Array.prototype.map()`

```html
<div id="parent-div">
    <div id="div-no-1"></div>
    <div id="div-no-2"></div>
    <div></div>
    <div class="div-no-2-6-6"></div>
    <div id="div-no-3"></div>
    <div id="div-no-4"></div>
    text
</div>
<script>
  let ids = [...document.querySelectorAll("#parent-div [id]")].map(({id}) => id);
  console.log(ids);
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

```
var ids = [];

$("#parent-div > div").each(function( index ) {
    ids.push($(this).attr('id'));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const ids = [];
jQuery.map(jQuery('#parent-div div'), function (elem, index) {
  if (elem) {
    ids.push(elem.getAttribute('id'));
  }
});
```

Using above code it find all div's from parent-div and iterate over it and fetch id attribute of each element and push into array

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.